Apply script when hovering over any element with a specific class
I am a Javascript novice and have been working on a script and it works!  It is a simple typewriter effect.  I want to apply it to all elements with the .type-me class attached.  Using querySelector, I got it to work on the first element but I'm not sure how to amend the script so that it works on any element that has the .type-me class attached.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
<script>
   var i = 0;
   var txt = document.querySelector('.type-me').textContent;
   document.querySelector('.type-me').textContent = '';
   document.querySelector('.type-me').removeAttribute('style');
   var speed = 500;
   type();
   function type() {
     if (i < txt.length) {
       document.querySelector('.type-me').textContent += txt.charAt(i);
       i++;
       setTimeout(type, speed);
     }
   }
</script>

I've tried using a combination of document.getElementsbyClassName and document.querySelectorAll but I have a feeling a loop is needed and I'm not great at writing loops just yet.

Have you look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll ?

You are correct that a loop is needed.
First, you'll need to gather all the DOM elements with the class into a node list and then you can loop over that and add the event handler:
Something like this:


document.querySelectorAll(".type-me").forEach(function(element){
  element.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event){

   var i = 0;
   // Within the event handler, the identifier: "this" refers to the element
   // that triggered the event. Using "this" allows for you to refer to the 
   // element without knowing which one it was or having to explicitly reference it.
   var txt = this.textContent;
   this.textContent = '';
   this.removeAttribute('style');
   var speed = 500;
   type(this);
   // When passing "this" to another function, the normal naming convention is to
   // receive "this" under the name "that".
   function type(that) {
     if (i < txt.length) {
       that.textContent += txt.charAt(i);
       i++;
       // Because "that" has to be passed as a parameter to the recursive setTimeout
       // call, we have to wrap the function call within an anonymous function that 
       // will actually call the real callback with the parameter.
       setTimeout(function(){type(that)}, speed);
     }
   }    
  });
});
<textarea class="type-me">Test Text</textarea>
<textarea class="type-me">Test Text</textarea>
<textarea class="type-me">Test Text</textarea>




Thank You! This was helpful.  I was able to get the hover effect working on each element.  However, when I hover on the second, third, etc. elements, the effect applies to the first element only not the the element that is being hovered over.  Any thoughts on what may be causing this in my code?

[document.querySelectorAll(".article-card").forEach(function(element){
element.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event){
var i = 0;
var txt = document.querySelector('.type-me').textContent;
document.querySelector('.type-me').textContent = '';
document.querySelector('.type-me').removeAttribute('style');
var speed = 500;
type();
function type() {
if (i < txt.length) {
document.querySelector('.type-me').textContent += txt.charAt(i);
i++;
setTimeout(type, speed);
}
}
});
});]

@SHADOWNUT See my updated answer with fully working code and comments.

Add an event handler to all the type-me class elements. Then in the event handler, use the current element being triggered's value to update the rest of the type-me elements.


document.querySelector('#app').innerHTML = `
<textarea class="type-me" placeholder="try it"></textarea> </br>
<textarea class="type-me" placeholder="try it"></textarea> </br>
<textarea class="type-me" placeholder="try it"></textarea> </br>
<textarea class="type-me" placeholder="try it"></textarea> </br>
`;

// Grab all the type-me class elements
const targets = document.querySelectorAll('.type-me');
for (let i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
  const target = targets[i];
  // and add an event handler to each one
  target.addEventListener('input', onChange);
}

// event function
function onChange(eventElement) {
  // go through each element
  for (let i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
    const target = targets[i];
    // check that the current target is not the
    // eventElement
    if (eventElement.target !== target) {
      // assign the eventElement's value to the target's
      const value = eventElement.target.value;
      target.value = eventElement.target.value;
    }
  }
}
:root {
  font-family: Inter, system-ui, Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 400;

  color-scheme: light dark;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.87);
  background-color: #242424;

  font-synthesis: none;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

a {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #646cff;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}
a:hover {
  color: #535bf2;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  place-items: center;
  min-width: 320px;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
<div id="app"></div>




Please don't link to code at 3rd party sites as those links can die over time, making your answer here meaningless. You can create executable code snippets right here at Stack Overflow by clicking the Stack Snippet icon (<>) when creating your questions or answers. I've edited your question to have this.

Also, this code does not do what the OP states they are trying to accomplish.

Your feedback and effort are appreciated. Thanks.
